# How to get anaconda/miniconda vs python versions mapping table?

Tags: python, anaconda, version, miniconda

For deep learning developers, anaconda/miniconda provide better python environment management.

However, creating a new conda environment also cost time. If I know each anaconda/miniconda distribution's default python version, I can choose that anaconda/miniconda to install, and don't have to create a new conda environment with different python version.

How can I generate a version mapping table between python and anaconda, between python and miniconda?

I've searched in the internet and found a table like this, but still don't know how to generate it:

[image: mapping]

ref: https://blog.csdn.net/yuejisuo1948/article/details/81043823

Comment: _...don’t have to create a new conda environment with different python version..._ Do you just use the base/root environment for everything?! D:

Comment: base environment for most things, and when have to create a new env for specific work/project, create that. This will save time for most thing, I think.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Don't know why my question got downvoted...The network connection is very bad sometimes in China for creating conda environment, since there are only several conda mirror in China. However, there are many python mirror site in China. If I can correctly choose a anaconda/miniconda distribution, I can then install pythono packages from mirror site. My experience is that conda mirror site are not stable so I ask this question.

Comment: Have you considered using `conda create --clone`? You could make template envs (which you would keep fixed) and clone them whenever you need a new project env. Not only does it avoid the internet, but for many packages it's mostly creating hardlinks, which avoids file duplication.

Comment: @HaxtraZ that is actually a really interesting situation. This has led me to do some research into conda and its performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/oldpkglists/`, this is the official site which gives the each anaconda's python version. People can use its original text, parse them, and generate a table. I didn't find miniconda's.

Comment: For miniconda (dated 2021): https://github.com/koverholt/anaconda-version-map#miniconda-versions