# How can I know a anaconda installer is for which python version?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install python3.7 by anaconda and the anaconda list is shown below:
[anaconda version list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bc5c.png)。
My question is how can I know a anaconda installer is for a special verison of python?

Actually, I know "Anaconda3-2020.05-Linux-x86_64.sh" is for python3.7。However, I am confused that by what infomation we can get the answer before we finish installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install specific version of python through the anaconda prompt, using:
`conda install python = 2.7.8` or `conda install python = 3.5.0` (for example).

You can even create a dedicated python environnement for a specific version:
`conda create --name py36 python=3.6`

Answer (score 1):

Anton B answer is correct, but if you just want to download the correct installer, you can use the following:

- For Anaconda you can use this: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/oldpkglists/
- For miniconda you can use the tables on the following page: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

A similar question was previously asked here:
[How to get anaconda/miniconda vs python versions mapping table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887525/how-to-get-anaconda-miniconda-vs-python-versions-mapping-table)